# Telegram bot / Stripe Integration bug - billing address look-up shows different results on different devices same account

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, telegram-bot

We recently completed a successful Telegram Bot / Stripe integration (standard API via @botfather).

Payments and checkout have been working fine until recently.

A bug in the billing address look-up function at checkout has occurred, however not for every user, some users can still complete checkout.

Bug

Using the same Telegram user account

If you follow the checkout process on desktop ALL billing country options provided by stripe appear in the telegram Stripe UI.

If you follow the same journey on Telegram iOS, only Andorra appears.

The same Telegram user account, both Apple products, different Apple devices got different results.

No problems were experienced yet on Android.

iPhone result:

[image: Iphone Result]

Desktop result:

[image: Desktop result]

Updated IOS and Telegram apps
Viewed all logs on Stripe - no were errors reported
Upgraded Stripe API
Posted questions to Telegram support

Below are the image file uploads from the Same Telegram account, 1 on desktop and 1 on iPhone IOS

iOS Stripe UI:

[image: IOS Stripe UI]

iOS stripe address look-up:

[image: IOS stripe address look-up]

iOS Stripe dropdowns:

[image: iOS Stripe dropdowns]

Desktop Stripe UI:

[image: Desktop Stripe UI]

Desktop Stripe address look-up:

[image: Desktop Stripe Address Look-up]

Desktop Stripe UI dropdowns:

[image: Desktop Stripe UI dropdowns]

Comment: Can you provide details on which Stripe payment UIs and APIs you're using Difficult to debug the potential issue without any technical details.

Comment: @JonathanSteele thanks for the response. Ive uploaded both user experiences, UI from both desktop and IOS. Same telegram account difference experiences. Its a standard API connection from stripe to telegram, with the key generated in botfather.